# how to use live with jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is sample code

```
$('#icons a').each(function(index) {

  $(this).attr('class','active');

});
```

If you look at the above code, what I am trying to do is for each anchor element I am adding a class called 'active' which are withing the DIV with id called 'icons'.

Problem what I am facing is by some other code I am adding new anchor elements after some interval of time.  I want to add this class to those anchors too.

Please suggest how we can achieve this with live / on / delegate.

Comment: First of all using duplicate id is invalid. also you need to re add the class after adding the DOM element.

Comment: When the "some other code" is adding the new `a` tags can it not add the `a` tags with the "active" class already set on them?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use each to add class to every anchor inside div with `id=icons`. 
Use below code:

```
$('#icons a').addClass('active');
```

And for adding class to the newly added anchor, add class at the same time when you are adding new anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#icons a').addClass('active');
```

Call the same function again after loading your dynamic data. If you are using $.get,$.post etc you can call this on "success"